# How to parse this string with PyParsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to parse :

```
'APPLE BANANA FOO TEST BAR'
```

into :

```
[['APPLE BANANA'], 'FOO', ['TEST BAR']]
```

Here is my latest attempt:

```
to_parse = 'APPLE BANANA FOO TEST BAR'
words = Word(alphas)
foo = Keyword("FOO")
parser = Group(ZeroOrMore(words + ~foo)) + foo + Group(ZeroOrMore(words))
result = parser.parseString(to_parse)
```

But it will return the following error:

```
>       raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
E       pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "FOO" (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)
```

I think that the problem comes from `ZeroOrMore(words + ~foo))` which is "too greedy". According to few questions on SO, the solution is to use that negation with `~foo`, but it doesn't work in this case. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. You just need to do the negative lookahead of `foo` *before* parsing a `words`:

```
parser = Group(ZeroOrMore(~foo + words)) + foo + Group(ZeroOrMore(words))
```

In recent pyparsing releases, I added a `stopOn` argument to `ZeroOrMore` and `OneOrMore` that does the same thing, to make this less error-prone:

```
parser = Group(ZeroOrMore(words, stopOn=foo)) + foo + Group(ZeroOrMore(words))
```

With this change I get:

```
>>> result.asList()
[['APPLE', 'BANANA'], 'FOO', ['TEST', 'BAR']]
```

Comment: Didn't know about this stopOn argument, thank you : )